# best practice for backup MySQL InnoDB tables?

Tags: mysql, innodb, database-backups, backup-strategies

What is the best practice for backing up MySQL InnoDB tables? (for myisam I use backuppc)

How can I do a backup and how can I restore it?

Thank you.

Comment: The best practice is using console command mysqldump i think

Comment: this site gives sols for worked code.so ask this in another portal

Answer (score 0):

> mysql> mysqldump -u username -ppassword databasename tablename  > Path
>   to save

you can schedule in in windows scheduler or in cron job after creating the batch file or SH file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'mysqldump' program from MySQL to dump individual tables..

shell> mysqldump [options] [tbl_name ...]

To restore the tables use command:

shell>mysql -uusername -ppassword -f -D databasename < /path/to/file/dbbackup.sql

Comment: shouldn't I use the **--single-transaction** option for making a consistent snapshot?

Comment: yes you should use it, useful for Innodb tables. I am using it.